# Add more than one value to a mysql table with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I got this code

```
    <form action="MyCurrentPage.php" method="post" >
    <label for="name_of_trainer"> Name Trainer </label>
    <input type="text" name="name_of_trainer" id="name_of_trainer"/>
    <label for="double"> yearly Income </label>
    <input type="text" name="yearly_income id="yearlyincome"/>
<input type= "submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $yearly_income_adition=$_POST['name_of_trainer'];
     $yearly_income=$_POST['yearly_income'];
     $mysqli->select_db("trainers");

    $sql="INSERT INTO trainers (titleCD, yearly_income) VALUES ('".$yearly_income_adition."','".$yearly_income.'")";
    $mysqli->query($sql);

     }

?>
```

and I am using it to insert new values into my database but it is not working, the values are not being added and I dont get any error. Do I have a syntax error?

Comment: this that code on the same page or different pages?

Comment: You can do select queries? Please check that

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, which means that if a hacker manages to walk by and play with your code, they can do things like delete all the tables in your database, or worse, obtain the information and find a way to profit from it.

Comment: After $yearly_income...I'm pretty sure it is supposed to be " then ' so:

$yearly_income."')";

Comment: you don't get any errors because you're not checking for them. unless you explicitly enable exceptions. mysqli fails by returning boolean false.

Comment: @MarcB - I think that's a PHP error there, not a mysql one

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO trainers (titleCD, yearly_income) VALUES ('".$yearly_income_adition."','".$yearly_income."')";
```

Notice the last new position of the last `'`

Also, as @Webeng commented, learn about [avoiding MySQL injection in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/459233). It's very important to have it as a habit.

Comment: 2 seconds before my comment, nice! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two things:

`?php` should be `<?php`

and

`'".$yearly_income.'")";`  should be `'".$yearly_income."')";`

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you check this?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

change it to:

```
if (isset($_POST['yearly_income'])) {
```